# React Js Data Table "No data available in table"

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble in React Js.
My data table is successfully populated but still showing "No data available in table" on the first row
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrZaL.jpg

This is screenshot of displayed html
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUxkz.jpg

Also when I using the sorting and search thingy all my data will be gone and just displays "No data available in table"

Network result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTOpZ.jpg
My code to display data from database

```
class Uptime extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/uptime')
            .then(res => res.json())
            // .then(res => res.text())          // convert to plain text
            // .then(text => console.log(text))
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        data: result.data
                    })
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    })
                }
            )
    }

    render() {
        const {error, isLoaded, data} = this.state;
        // if (error) {
        //     return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        // } else if (!isLoaded) {
        //     return (
        //         <div className="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
        //             <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        //         </div>
        //     )
        // } else {    WHEN I ADD THIS CODE, THE SEARCH FUNCTION AND SORT FUNCtION IS GONE , SO I JUST REMOVE IT
        return (
            <div id="content-wrapper" className="d-flex flex-column">
                <div id="content">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="card shadow mb-4 mt-5">
                            <div className="card-header py-3 text-center">
                                <h6 className="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">DataTables Example</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <div className="table-responsive">
                                    <table className="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%"
                                           cellSpacing="0">

                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th width="10%">Name</th>
                                            <th width="40%">Url</th>
                                            <th width="10%">Downtime</th>
                                            <th width="20%">date</th>
                                            <th width="10%">Status Code</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                          {data.map(item => (
                                                        <tr key={item[0]}>
                                                        <td>{item[1]}</td>
                                                        <td>{item[2]}</td>
                                                        <td>{item[5]}</td>
                                                        <td>{item[4]}</td>
                                                        <td>{item[3]}</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                      ))}
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <footer className="sticky-footer bg-white">
                    <div className="container my-auto">
                        <div className="copyright text-center my-auto">
                            <span>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2019</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>

            </div>

        )

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, i.e. the component code that fetches, processes, and renders the data.

Comment: Please share the full code so that we can help you here.

Comment: Ive update my code , please check

Comment: Looks like "No data available in table" is part of your data that is being mapped into the DOM. Can you also provide your response from network? Unlikely but I wonder if it's a react key issue.

Comment: @DrewReese, Nope "No data available in table" is NOT part of my data

Comment: @Yan Go to network tab, then click into request which is made by you. There you can find Header and Response. So in the Response you can check what data is returned. Or you can just add console.log(result.data, result)

Comment: Are you sure? You start with empty array, fetch some "data", and render a bunch of rows and the first row has text "No data available in table". These are the only clues so far. If you share the response shape from network it'd be easy to rule weird data out.

Comment: I've uploaded the picture now, also im sure i am display all the data in JSON format

Comment: Do you at some point display a table with *just* the single row for "No data..." with react key `1`, and then later the fetched data populates and it all updates except for the first row?

Comment: @Yan, which plugin are you using for datatable?

Comment: @DrewReese, By default is just  empty table, then i just add all the data from the flask api. thats it no more additional function which i add data again to the table

Comment: @VivekDoshi, I am not sure, [jquery.dataTables.min.js,dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js] are you referring to these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Issue :**
>
> Datatable is being initialized before the data comes, so it will show
>   "No data available in table" , once table is initialized then after
>   you are making changes in that table , so you data got append after
>   the row "No data available in table" , you can check that issue by
>   running below snippet.

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {

  const [users,setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setUsers([[0,"Vivek"],[1,"Darshita"]]);
    },2000);
  },[]);

  return (
    <table className="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellSpacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="10%">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {
            users.map(item => (
                    <tr key={item[0]}>
                        <td>{item[1]}</td>
                    </tr>))
        }
    </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

> **Solution :**
>
> As `datatable` is being initialized automatically, you have to destroy
>   it before setting up the state and and reinitialized it once data is
>   available, as you can see the same in the below snippet

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {

  const [users,setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#dataTable').DataTable().destroy();
      setUsers([[0,"Vivek"],[1,"Darshita"]]);
    },2000);
  },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
      $('#dataTable').DataTable();
  },[users]);

  return (
    <table className="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellSpacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="10%">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {
            users.map(item => (
                    <tr key={item[0]}>
                        <td>{item[1]}</td>
                    </tr>))
        }
    </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: let me try this and will get back with the result :)

Comment: "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:" I still dont know about useEffects so I cant seem to make this work :), althought I got your logic on how to solve it

Comment: You have to put that in `componentDidMount` , put `$('#dataTable').DataTable().destroy();` before fetch and `$('#dataTable').DataTable();` after you fetch the data

Comment: @Yan, check now

Comment: I have added an error on the code link, I think this is already related to jquery

Comment: @Yan, nope, it's exactly working fine, it's just us who is executing in wrong flow. i would suggest you to use , react npm packages instead of directly loading js files, like https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/datatables/, in this all the render process , reinit, destroyed will be handled automatically

Comment: Ok, will look into that, I'm just a beginner and just following random tutorials
Thanks for the help, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution have no sense but solved this problem for me :

```
useEffect(()=>{
        const timer = setTimeout(function () {
            ApplyDataTable()// here you call the datatable logic 
        }, 0);  // you see here , it run immediatly no ,dely !!!!but it solve it :D
        return () => clearTimeout(timer);

})
```